# Help with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln\left( \frac{(n+1)^2}{n(n+2)} \right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, telescopic-series

To what number the telescoping series converges,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln\left( \frac{(n+1)^2}{n(n+2)} \right)$$

---

I already applied the log property of
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln((n+1)^2) - \ln(n)(n+2)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2\ln(n+1) - \ln(n) - \ln(n+2)$$

we know that
$$2\ln(n+1) = \ln(n+1) + \ln(n=1)$$

re-writing as two telescoping series:

$$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(n) - \ln(n+1) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(n+1) - \ln(n+2)$$

The limit of the partial sum will be:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(2) - \ln(1) - \ln(n+2) + \ln(n+1) \\ = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left( ln(2)  + \ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right) \right) \\
= \ln(2) $$

i'd like to know if i'm correct bc the awnser i got is the same as the book

*PS:*
*sorry for my poor formatting and English*

Comment: Your steps are nearly correct, but when you evaluate the last telescoping sums you'll get something of the form $\infty - \infty$. To work around this, try summing to a fixed value say $x$ rather than infinity. This way, you can evaluate the telescoping sums, and combine the two to get some convergent expression. Then just let $x$ approach infinity to get your answer.

Comment: Yes, i have summed the partial sums and get a expression for them 
 $S_n = \ln(2) + \ln(1) -\ln(n+2) + \ln(n+1) => \lim_{n \to\infty} S_n = ln(2)$

Comment: That's correct, it's more formal to take partial sums and then a limit than deal with differences of infinite sums.